# Location on Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, location

I have a rails app and I want to track if a user of the app is accessing the app from a computer inside a specific venue or office.

I will like to know if my users are accessing from our venue or at their home (any other location). I have tried geocoder gem but its is not very accurate, the other option was using an ip, but my internet provider gives me dynamic ips.

What can I use to solve this problem?

One thing i have also tried is accessing my computers mac address but from what I have been reading, for security reasons there is no way to access this number.

Comment: I think your best bet is to ask user to enable HTMl5 geolocation which works close to perfect. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp . Use these features wisely :)

Comment: We've been using it, but there's a chance for the users to do a fake GPS geolocation, is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Not sure why your targeted users is someone who is faking his/her geolocation. Also, if they are faking it then it means they don't want to share these data and you should respect it on my personal opinion. Ideally a developer shouldn't be worried too much about location.